# Can't get a Java program to work - it won't find jvm.dll

Tags: java, windows

I received an old Java program from a colleague, and tried to run it on Windows 10.   First I had to install Java, which I did.   Then I ran the program's install exe, and it gave an error: "could not load jvm.dll".

So I looked for jvm.dll and found it in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\client.

I then added it to the System-Environmental-Variables specifically the PATH variable.  This did not solve the problem.

I've never worked with Java, and it seems to be rejected by the major browsers, probably for security reasons, but this is a valuable program.   Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer?

Comment: It's uncommon for a Java program to have an "install exe" at all, so I suspect the issue has something to do with how the program is being installed. Normally you would have a small launcher that finds the appropriate JVM and lanuches it, but you should be able to skip that launcher and launch the Java runtime directly. The exact command line depends on how the rest of the application is installed.